# Testing methods using jest in typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need some help and I am very new to Jest. Here is the snippet and I am passing Json as an input, can you please help in writing the Jest test cases for testing the Call ID/SectionId is a Number and  SectionName is a String and also input is a Json.

```
class sections {
    constructor() {   
    }
    public getSections(section): void {
        for (let k = 0; k<section.length; k++){
        console.log('CallId: '+section[k].CallId+', SectionId: 
        '+section[k].SectionId+', SectionName:  '+section[k].SectionName);
            }                   
    }
}    
export default new sections();
```

Comment: Thanks Scott and sorry, I started something on this but no where I am getting to but let me post what I have.

Comment: Thanks Scott and sorry, I want to find out want to find out the Call ID/SectionId is a Number and SectionName is a String and also input is a Json. Some how ,I couldn't able to validate the values, just simple clue will help     
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as shalllow from 'enzyme';
import sections from './../src/sections'
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { describe } from 'mocha';
describe('Sections', () => {
    it('should return Json', () => {
        let section;
        const result=sections.getSections(section);
        expect(result).to.equal('json');
    })
});

Comment: I would update your question with this last comment as it will view considerably better.  Your Jest test can test the type of a value (typeof) to be true to see if it is a number or string.